# Why can't KVL be applied here?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, basic, kirchhoffs-laws

I was asked to find the Is current
[image]

I applied KVL in that loop but my ans is wrong.
what concept is wrong on my approach?Why kvl cant be applied on that loop please explain
[image]

Comment: Do you have to use KVL?  I think the current law makes more sense here.  You know the 2A already.   There's 10V across BOTH resistors (don't be confused by how the circuit is drawn).  Since they're both 10V, you can calculate the currents in them easily.   Then use KCL to find "IS"

Comment: You did not actually apply KVL. You applied a weird and incomplete mix of KCL and KVL. You have 3 loops, yet only one loop equation. You can't just solve a loop in isolation because everything present affects everything else. You solve for it all.

Comment: KVL is valid always. What you did here isn't KVL.

Comment: And there is also a hole in your logic for the KCL you tried to apply at the top center node. You wrote that the current flowing out to the right is 2-Is, but it's not, because the current flowing down is not Is. The current flowing through the battery and only the battery is Is. The current flowing down is a combination of Is and that through the 2 Ohm resistor.

Comment: KVL holds. There is 10V across the 1\$\Omega\$ resistor, and 10V across the 2\$\Omega\$ resistor.

Comment: @DKNguyen Thanks for clarifying...i have a single doubt why the 2ohm resistor's current is not supplied entirely by the 10V source?..if 5v flows through it the kvl gets satisfied in that small loop

Comment: @ParanBharali There's 5 A + 10 A flowing upward out of the 10 V source, ignoring the current source. Then the current source provides 2 A of that. So what's 5 A + 10 A - 2 A? That will be moving in the opposite direction of the arrow. But it's really simple KCL. The 5 Ohm resistor isn't even relevant, since the current source has infinite impedance. You can just short it out, if you want.

Comment: The manner in which the schematic is drawn is designed to trick the student.  Just draw the 2-ohm resistor across the top and bottom horizontal wires (instead of connected closer to the 10VDC power supply, and you'll see the problem.  You are currently not accounting for one branch of current.

Comment: @ParanBharali If you want to use KVL, then [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HKLR9.png) shows you the loops to use. Do notice that this is the exact same schematic you have, just redrawn slightly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the current through \$ 1\Omega\$ is not \$2-I_s\$ as you have assumed. It is actually = \$2-(I_s+I_{2\Omega})\$, where \$I_{2\Omega} = 10/2 = 5A\$. You didn't see that there are actually 4 branches at the upper node where you split the current using KCL. Not 3 branches. \$2\Omega\$ is the branch you missed. I think \$2\Omega\$ was deliberately drawn like that to trick students.